# I want to record android screen not full screen only a part of screen

Tags: android, screenshot

I know we can record android screen, using `mediaProjection` and by using `virtualdisplay`. But i want to record a specific part of screen. i.e a fragment not entire activity. Please help me to solve this problem

[image: I want to record only area of screen in RED Box.]

Comment: If your region happens to be starting in the upper left hand corner, you may be able to get away with using your desired width and height in the call to `createVirtualDisplay()`. I do not see how you can specify to start at some other pixel coordinate. Worst-case, you would need to record the whole screen, then use `ffmpeg` or something to post-process it and crop only the region that you need.

Comment: Okay, lets say my Red box starts from Left upper corner and end at same location. How to do that?

Comment: As I wrote in my comment, you may be able to get away with using your desired width and height in the call to `createVirtualDisplay()`. So, if you want a 100x200 region, pass 100 and 200 to `createVirtualDisplay()` for the width and height. I have not tried this, and so I do not know if this will crop the output, scale the output, do something else, or fail horribly.

Comment: Okay, i will try.. Thank you

Comment: @MuhammadHasnain DId you get a solution to this ?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?